# Wrap text between HTML inside Vue filter

Tags: javascript, string, vue.js

In vuejs, is it possible to wrap certain parts of the text inside HTML tags?

Like `Hello %John%. How are you doing?`
to become `Hello <b>%John%</b>. How are you doing?`

with a filter like

```
{{text | wrapText}}
```

Comment: Did you have a a look at https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/custom-filter.html  ?

Comment: yes but there is no mention of html

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own filter. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eh4k6fqd/1/)

```
Vue.filter('wrapText', function (text) {
  let a = text.split('%');
  let str = '';
  for (let x = 0; x < a.length; x++) {
    str += a[x];
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        if (x < a.length - 1)
        str += '<b>';
    }
    else {
        str += '</b>';
    }
  }
  return str
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I **never** worked with `vue` but I read a little bit in the last 15 mins and i guess i found a solution.

You can play around with the javaScript method.There might be a cleaner way to achieve the same result.

The important fact is to use the vue custom filters with `:inner-html.prop`. It doesn't look very 'safe' but if you control what html gets inserted there you should be ok.

So in html you can do something like
`<span :inner-html.prop="text | wrapText"></span>`

And then declare your filter. I read there are two ways to declare them: globally or inside the component, you choose.

Globally

```
Vue.filter('wrapText', function (value) {
  const wordToWrap = value.substring(
    value.indexOf("%")+1, 
    value.lastIndexOf("%")
  )

  const wrappedWord = `<b>${wordToWrap}</b>`

  value = value.replace(wordToWrap, wrappedWord)

  return value;
})
```

And this should work. I got it to work on a vue playground.
Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Regex is the way :D

Edit: "2.0 filters only work in mustache tags and v-bind."

cfr: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4352

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    text: 'Hello %John%. How are you doing %today%?'
  },
  filters: {
    wrapText(str) {
      return this.wrapText(str)
    }
  },
  methods: {
      wrapText(str) {
     if (str.includes('%')) {
          const reg = /(%[A-Za-z0-9]*%)/g
          const newStr = str.replace(reg, '<b>$1</b>')
          return newStr
        }
        return str
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <h2>This is a text</h2>
  <p v-html="wrapText(text)">
  </p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

The `filter` part is no longer needed but I've left it anyway.

Comment: good idea with the regex. The problem was not the filter but how to insert HTML. `<b>%John%</b>` doesn't look html to me :)

Comment: I forgot the last part, sorry. I am going to fix it. Fixed!